# how to make sum of row level data in sas

Tags: sas

I want to do row level sum in sas

Here i did sum of C D E row and calculate in F row .I checked with sum case when condition but doesnt work.

I tried using several case when condition ,separate datasets but doesnt work

for example

```
Name v1 v2 v3
A    2  3  4
B    3  5  6
C    3  4  4
D    2  5  2
E    1  2  6
F    6  11 12
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Please show a sample input data set, and clearly indicate what data you want to output.

Comment: Show what you've tried please.

Comment: It would help if you show what you had to start, what you want as final output and what you've tried. https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/Insert-a-Row-at-the-end-of-the-data-with-totals/td-p/136539

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a datastep too:

```
data want;
  set have end = lastrec;

  retain v1_sum 0;
  retain v2_sum 0;
  retain v3_sum 0;

  /* Better to use sum() than + since it deals with missing values better */

  if Name in ('C', 'D', 'E') then do;
    v1_sum = sum(v1_sum, v1);
    v2_sum = sum(v2_sum, v2);
    v3_sum = sum(v3_sum, v3);
  end;

  output;

  if lastrec then do;
    Name = "F";
    v1 = v1_sum;
    v2 = v2_sum;
    v3 = v3_sum;
    output;
  end;
  drop v1_sum v2_sum v3_sum;
run;
```

Comment: OP only wants to add specific rows, C, D and E.

Comment: Thanks @Reeza. I fixed the solution to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Proc MEANS` to aggregate the desired rows.  Then, a data step can stack the original data and the aggregate by way of a `SET` statement.

```
data have; input
Name $1. v1 v2 v3; datalines;
A    2  3  4
B    3  5  6
C    3  4  4
D    2  5  2
E    1  2  6
run;

proc means data=have noprint;
  where name in ('C','D','E');
  output out=aggregate(keep=v1-v3) sum(v1-v3)=v1-v3;
run;

data want; 
  set
    have
    aggregate(in=sums)
  ;
  if sums then name = 'F';
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` and `union all`

```
select name,v1,v2,v3 from table
union all
select 'F' sum(v1),sum(v2),sum(v3)
(
select *,row_number() over(order by Name) rn
from table
) a where a.rn>=3 adn a.rn<=5
```

Comment: row_number() isn't valid in SAS SQL. Monotonic will work though.